# "Compile Error - Sub or Error Function Not Defined" Excel VBA Error for Trying to Filter Across Columns

Tags: excel

I am trying to find an excel VBA macro that allows me to filter across columns instead of rows. If anyone has any code or a template for excel that already does that, please share.

Otherwise I was watching a video that had code that'd do exactly what I want. However, when I do the keyboard shortcut for "FillFilters" I get the error message "Compile Error - Sub or Error Function Not Defined". Can anyone help on this issue? Code is posted below, thanks

```vb
Sub FillFilters() 'with sortcut
        Dim oRange As Range, l As Long, r As Long, c As Long, sFilter As String, arr As Variant, sTemp As String, bDone As Boolean
        If Range("A1") = "Filters" Then Exit Sub
        Range("A2").EntireColumn.Insert
        Set oRange = Sheet4.Range("A2").CurrentRegion
        With oRange
                .Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                .Cells(1, 1) = "Filters"
                For r = 2 To .Rows.Count
                    For c = 3 To .Columns.Count
                        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(Cells(r, 3), Cells(r, c)), Cell(r, c)) = 1 Then
                            sFilter = sFilter & "," & Cells(r, c)
                        End If
                    Next c
                    arr = Split(sFilter, ",")
                    Do
                        bDone = True
                        For I = 1 To UBound(arr) - 1
                            If arr(I) > arr(I + 1) Then
                                bDone = False: sTemp = arr(I): arr(I) = arrr(I + 1): arr(I + 1) = sTemp
                            End If
                    Next I
                Loop While bDonw = False
                sFilter = Join(arr, ",")
                With .Cells(r, I).Validation
                    .Delete
                    .Add Type:=xiValidateList, Formula1:="-" & sFilter & ",Blanks"
                    .InCellDropdown = True
                End With
                sFilter = ""
            Next r
            .Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        End With
             
    
End Sub

Sub DeleteFilters() 'with shortcut
    If Range("A1") = "Filters" Then
        Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Range("A1").EntireColumn.Delete
        Range("A1").Select
    End If
        
End Sub

Sub Filtering(oFIlter As Range)
    Dim oRange As Range, sCell As String, r As Long, c As Long, iRow As Long, iCount As Long
    Set oRange = Sheet1.Range("A2").CurrentRegion
    sCell = oFIlter.Value
    If sCell = "Filters" Then oRange.Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False: Exit Sub
    If sCell = "" Then oRange.Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False: Exit Sub
    If sCell = "-" Then oRange.Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False: Exit Sub
    If sCell = "Blanks" Then oRange.Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False: sCell = ""
    oRange.Cells.EntireColmn.Hidden = False
    iRow = oFIlter.Row
    With oRange
        For c = 3 To .Columns.Count
            If .Cells(iRow, c) <> sCell Then
                .Cell(iRow, c).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Else
                iCount = iCount + 1
            End If
        Next c
        MsgBox iCount & " columns for row " & iRow
    End With
                
    
End Sub

Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Range("A1") <> "FIlters" Then Exit Sub
    If Target Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Column = 1 Then Filtering Target
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Range("A1") <> "Filters" Then Exit Sub
    If Target Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Column <> 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Value = "" Then Exit Sub
    Filtering Target
```

Comment: Are you using `Option Explicit` to force variable declaration? Errors like the one you have here are often due to typos. Or maybe something else.

Comment: This is just a typo. You have `Cell` in a place where you mean `Cells`. You should have been able to debug it yourself. In the VBA editor use `Compile` in the `Debug` menu option and it would have instantly highlighted the offending typo. Once I copy-pasted your code it took me less than a minute to discover the problem.